# android studio not showing me option for create project from existing sources for developing phonegap

Tags: android, cordova

i am new in android platform and installed android studio for app creation 
i have to develop a application for mobile using phonegap
succesfully insatalled requirements but as the tutorial suggest me to import the project into android studio then select option "`create project from existing resources`"

but when i open `file` > `new` > `import project` > and select the path then next it ask me for destination not "`create project from existing sources`" and finish step

the screen i found is given below:[image]

please let me know where i am doing wrenter image description hereong or any good tutorial links for phonegap application creation.

i am using android studio 1.2.1.1 and this tutorial for reference http://www.codenutz.com/getting-started-phonegap-android-studio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open Android studio 1.2.1.1, you should see a welcome screen with a "Quick start" tab.

In the Quick start tab, just click on "Import project(Eclipse ADT, Graddle, etc.)" to import the cordova project to android studio.

Then you browse to the Platforms/android folder of your project and click ok to import it.

From the sreen in your question, clicking on the "close project" button should open the welcome screen.